# Does Stellan smoke cinnamon tobacco or chocolate tobacco?

Tags: continuity, imaginarium-geographica, james-a-owen

In the first book of *The Chronicles of the Imaginarium Geographica*, *Here There Be Dragons*, Stellan Sigurdsson is told to have smoked a special mix of cinnamon and tobacco.

> "Yes, I can.  It's a tobacco of some kind."
>   "A cinnamon tobacco," said John. "A special mix."

But later, in *The Shadow Dragons* (book 4), he's mentioned as smelling of chocolate tobacco.

> An instant later he could smell that familiar chocolate-tobacco mixture, as his old mentor and teacher stepped down from the frame.

Is this an error (possibly in my copy only) in the book?  Or is he mentioned as smoking both?

Answer (score 8):

The (error?) tobacco reference is also found in my (eBook) copy. In-universe there are a few possible options.

- It's described in *Here, There Be Dragons* as a "*special cinnamon tobacco **mix***". Presumably it's ***mixed*** with something else, possibly chocolate.
- John is extremely surprised to see the Professor. Perhaps in his haste and shock he simply misspoke, mistaking cinnamon for chocolate.

Out-of-universe it's fairly obviously a writing error, perhaps one that will be corrected in a future edition.

Comment: I don't it's #2, it's referenced other places also. But thanks for answering.

Comment: @riker - The word chocolate only appears 5 times in all seven of the Imaginarium books, and only once in connection with tobacco. By comparison, the word cinnamon appears eight times, all in connection with tobacco (with one exception) but all in the same book. It seems most likely that the author simply mis-remembered (3 years later) what the tobacco was supposed to smell like.

Comment: 1. there are 7 books? 2. Yeah, that's true.

Comment: @Riker - It saddens me that you didn't like my answer. I've prodded the author on twitter. Hopefully they'll weigh in with a better (or at least more authoritative) answer for you.

Comment: It's not about your answer being bad as much as it is that this is the answer. to rephrase that, it's not about you, it's about the (lack-of) a good answer.